# How do you send a DM using a discord bot using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a bot that has a command to send a "ticket", which is like a warning except it sends a configurable message in a DM. Here's my code so far:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const token = token here;
const PREFIX = '/';
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
bot.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log('This bot is online! Created by @littleBitsman.');
})

bot.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'ticket':
      if (message.member.roles.highest == '701895573737046066') {
        mention = message.mentions.users.first()
        var thing = args.shift()
        thing = args.shift()
        thing = thing.replace(",", " ")
        if(mention = null) {return}
        var message = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Ticket')
          .setDescription('Hey ' + mention + '! You recieved this because of: ' + args +'.')
        message.channel.type(`dm`) + message.channel.send(mentionMessage)
      }
      }
  })
bot.login(token);
```

I took out all other code that did not have to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a message to a specific user, you can do `` message.client.users.fetch(`insert_ID`).then(user => user.send('message')) ``.

It seems like you're trying to send a message to a user that was mentioned. In that case:

`` message.client.users.fetch(`${mention.id}`).then(user => user.send('insert_message')) ``.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Now I am receiving an error that says ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null```. And if I remove ```id``` from ```${mention.id}```, the error is ```(node:8560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "null" is not snowflake.```

Comment: Try making a variable under the mention variable called mentionID. Give it the value of `mention.id`. Then instead of `${mention.id}`, do `${mentionID}`

Comment: Now it is giving this error with an arrow pointed at ```id```: ```mentionID = mention.id```

Comment: Maybe try to make another variable called, for example mentioned, and give it the value of `message.mentions.members.first()` and for `mentionID`, instead of mention.id, do mentioned.id 

(Basically means you have a variable called mention and another one called mentioned) `mention` is defined as `message.mentions.users.first()` and `mentioned` is defined as `message.mentions.members.first()`